# Class 'App\Order' not found

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-routing, laravel-query-builder, laravel-scout

I'm working with Laravel Scout for the first time, and I use the documentation form here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout#searching.

After following all the steps and adding to my route files

```
 Route::get('warbands/search', function (Request $request) {
 return App\Order::search($request->search)->get();
 });
```

I get Class 'App\Order' not found.

Am I missing something I have to include?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Order model namespaced correctly?

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    use Searchable;
    ...
}
```

If so, perhaps you need to run `composer dumpautoload`.

Answer (score 0):

"use App\Models\Order"  probably can fix it;

Comment: Elaborate on how it can resolve the OP's issue.